# How to use data outside of function returned from POST or GET method of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to use data outside of function returned from POST or GET method of jquery?

My question is i'm getting some data through jquery post method.. the problem is whenever i get data i'm just able to use that within function actually i want that data to use outside of function.. as i alerted data outside function it's not working...

```
function getlatlanfromjs() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var uid = $(".track_textbox").val();

        $.post("getLatLan.php", {userid: uid}, function(data) {
            var i;
            for (i = 1; i < 2; i++) {                
                initialize(data[i]["latitude"], data[i]["longitude"]);
            }
        }, "json");

        alert(data[1]["latitude"]); //this is actually not alerting..  what is the reason ?
    });
}
```

Comment: It's probably calling alert() before the post request returns, that's AJAX for you.

Comment: If you want to alert outside of the callback, you need to use a promise. Look into jQuery deferred to see how it works.

Comment: That's exactly what it's doing @xd6_, it's an Asynchronous request. Why not just continue your code from within the function with the response data? Call a function from there and continue your code.

Comment: take a look at the last example in [https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), I think the .done method is what you are looking for

Comment: @Joe - the function(data) argument to $.post is just that, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because **data** variable is out of scope at that point. Code below will assign the **data** to the local **recievedData** and you can use it out of the handling function scope. Though you will still be only able to access recievedData variable only when request is done.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var recievedData;
    var uid = $(".track_textbox").val();


    var promise = $.post("getLatLan.php", {userid: uid}, function(data) {
        recievedData = data;
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i < 2; i++) {

            initialize(data[i]["latitude"], data[i]["longitude"]);

        }



    }, "json");

   promise.done(function() {
    alert(recievedData[1]["latitude"]); });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

this is a bit better...

This way you dont miss the execution. If you wrap your code into a closure, you can call it later too. So even though your "getlatlanfromjs" has already executed, your alertFn still exists and will be called when the `$.post` is done.

> function getlatlanfromjs() {
>       $(document).ready(function() {
>           var uid = $(".track_textbox").val();
>
> ```
>     var alertFn = function(data) { alert(data[1]["latitude"]); };
>
>     $.post("getLatLan.php", {userid: uid}, function(data) {
>         var i;
>         for (i = 1; i < 2; i++) {                
>             initialize(data[i]["latitude"], data[i]["longitude"]);
>         }
>         alertFn(data);
>     }, "json");
>
> }); }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
   var mydata = null;

    function getlatlanfromjs() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var uid = $(".track_textbox").val();

        $.post("getLatLan.php", {userid: uid}, function(data) {
            mydata = data;
            var i;
            for (i = 1; i < 2; i++) {                
                initialize(data[i]["latitude"], data[i]["longitude"]);
            }
        }, "json");
        if(mydata != null)   alert(data[1]["latitude"]); 
    });
}
```

All you needed to do was keep track of the scope of data.